# Actions on Google brand name ownership verification for website not app

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to create an alpha release of a dialogflow agent in the Actions on Google Console and am being blocked by Brand Verification. I have verified my website but it continues to tell me on the Invocation page that Company Name is a reserved brand name. Verify ownership here.

[image: actions on google reserved brand name]

When I click the "here" link it takes me to this page that says my website is connected.

[image: actions on google website connected]

At this point I'm really confused. **Do I need to connect my app as well?** It's not clear that both are mandatory. I would think that connecting the website should be enough. Any clarification here would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Have you filed a [support ticket](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/)?

Comment: @NickFelker I just did. Awaiting a response from them.

Comment: I am having the same problem and the support ticket page is chucking an error so I can't submit a request :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I filled out the form on the [Actions on Google Support page](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/) and they emailed that they were looking into it and then they emailed again later telling that they had approved me. Not sure what the problem was, but the support ticket got things fixed. Thanks @NickFelker for the suggestion.

**UPDATE**

I ran into another bit of trouble with this. After getting this fixed by Actions on Google support it didn't let me publish but kept on giving me the verify ownership error. I emailed support back and they looked into it. Apparently the error message wasn't very helpful and it didn't actually have anything to do with verifying ownership. **The real problem was that my invocation phrase was a domain name (like Example.com) and as soon as I clicked the "Modify the pronunciation if it doesn't sound right" button and added an alternate pronunciation of "Example dot com" I was able to publish my app.**

¯\_(ツ)_/¯